# Ionic 2: Add Class to Item While Removing Class From Other Items

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I have a div full of buttons that, when clicked, should add a class (`selected-date-item`) that changes the color of the button. Immediately before that, I want to remove that class (`selected-date-item`) from any button that previously held that class.

**CSS**

```
.selected-date-item {
  background:#272829;
  color:white;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="date-time-select" *ngFor="let chooseDate of possibleDates" (tap)="selectPickupDate(chooseDate)">{{chooseDate}}</button>
```

**JS**

```
selectPickupDate(selectedDate) {
  this.selectedDate = selectedDate;
}
```

[image] => [image]

Comment: something like <span *ngFor="let chooseDate of possibleDates" ><button class="date-time-select" (tap)="selectPickupDate(chooseDate)"  [ngClass]="chooseDate== selectedDate) ? 'selected-date-item' : '">

Comment: @Rienk slightly confusing - is there a parentheses that needs to be closed?

Comment: Yes, parentheses needs to be opened: [ngClass]="-->(<--chooseDate== selectedDate) ? 'selected-date-item' : '"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[ngClass]`-directive to set a CSS-class dynamically .

```
<button [ngClass]="{'selected-date-item': chooseDate == selectedDate, 'not-selected-item': chooseDate != selectedDate}" *ngFor="let chooseDate of possibleDates" (tap)="selectPickupDate(chooseDate)">{{chooseDate}}</button>
```

**`[ngClass]` broken out:**

```
[ngClass]="{'selected-date-item': chooseDate == selectedDate, 'not-selected-item': chooseDate != selectedDate}"
```